# Is there a special name for graphs that have "check board" property?

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a special name for a graph, all vertices of which can be divined into two sets in such a way, that any edge connects vertices of different sets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a **[bipartite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph)** (or **2-colorable**) graph.

Comment: Thanks for a quick and correct answer!